# Auto alignment of data in Xtext

Tags: xtext

I had one custom parser rule in which I had defined all my keywords such as _self, _for, _loop etc. Because of this, if I type _s and click Ctrl+ space bar, it shows _self.But what I required is even though I type self or SE, it should auto assign as _self.Is it possible? If so, could anyone please suggest a solution for this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to be payed attention to

1. There needs to be a proposal and only one proposal. Otherwise the user has to select the prosal to be applied and no auto insert takes places
2. Proposals are created based on the error recovery and so you might not get the proposal you are looking for at all

so lets assume you have a grammar like

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    '_self' name=ID '!';
```

and a model file like

```
SE
```

Then the error recovery will work fine an a proposal of "_self" will be added to the list of proposals

3. Proposals are Filtered based on the current prefix in the model. that would be the place you could start customizing.

e.g. this very naive impl

```
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.FQNPrefixMatcher;

public class MyPrefixMatcher extends FQNPrefixMatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean isCandidateMatchingPrefix(String name, String prefix) {
        return super.isCandidateMatchingPrefix(name, prefix) || super.isCandidateMatchingPrefix(name, "_" + prefix);
    }

}
```

and dont forget to bind

```
import org.eclipse.xtend.lib.annotations.FinalFieldsConstructor
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.contentassist.PrefixMatcher
import org.xtext.example.mydsl4.ui.contentassist.MyPrefixMatcher

@FinalFieldsConstructor
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {

    override Class<? extends PrefixMatcher> bindPrefixMatcher() {
        return MyPrefixMatcher;
    }

}
```

4. There is another feature that does not use proposals at all but the text that is actually typed and if it recognizes something then can replace it with something else. this feature is called "Auto Edit". The extension point in xtext for this is `IAutoEditStrategy` / `AbstractEditStrategyProvider`

Comment: Hi Christian Dietrich ,can u please suggest one more way

Comment: Have no idea what your problem is

Comment: Thank u so much Christian Dietrich the answer you suggested is working fine